# Missing "Web Site" item on Azure Portal. Can not create a new Web Site

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to create a new web site on Azure.  When I use my account on Azure, the "Web Site" option is missing. Thanks for any advises.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look for App Services, or Web Apps. Hasn't been called "Web Sites" in a very long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David said, now the Azure App Service brings **together** the capabilities from **Azure Websites**, **Azure Mobile Service**, and **Azure BizTalk Services** into a unique integrated offering.

We can login to [Azure new portal](https://portal.azure.com) to fine the Azure app.

More information about web site and Azure app, please refer to this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-app-service/).